# My 4 year old daughter has suddenly changed her speech

Tags: pre-schooler, speech

My 4 year old daughter has all of a sudden changed her accent drastically to one that is awful. The pronunciation is totally incorrect and its freaking me out. The more I correct the worse it becomes. Should I take her for speech and drama classes?

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is happening? Friends with different accents, perhaps? Anything?

Comment: Just to be sure: Have there been *any other* changes in her lfe lately? Family, home, new surroundings, caregiver, .... anything? Has she changed (other than the speech) or made some bigger steps in her development?

Comment: Definitely need more info before any of us can help.

Comment: Is she in preschool? My daughter suddenly talks like a troll and I can't stand the voice, so I just pretend everything she says is telling me to throw candy in the trash. She stops when she thinks I am throwing candy away (which I usually keep in my pocket for this reason)

Comment: Have you asked her why she talks differently? She might just be doing it for amusement.

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth getting her hearing checked, a sudden change might indicate a change in the feed-back loop between what she says and what she hears.

At age 4, my son's adenoids closed off his Eustachian tubes thus filling his inner ears with liquid and reducing his hearing significantly. Many children's Eustachian do not fully develop until the age of 8.